# Изменение класса блока в зависимости от размеров экрана

Tags: javascript, html, css

я имею блок с классом "preview_main_button" ( `<div class="preview_main_button" id="ButtonOnPreview">Перейти ко всем статьям</div>` ), но я хочу, чтобы на экранах разрешение которых меньше 769 пикселей его класс менялся на "preview_main_button_2" - каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: Правильнее это сделать стилями используя `@media`.

Answer (score 0):

Пример взял от сюда https://toster.ru/q/593928

```js
(function() {
    var throttle = function(type, name, obj) {
        obj = obj || window;
        var running = false;
        var func = function() {
            if (running) { return; }
            running = true;
             requestAnimationFrame(function() {
                obj.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(name));
                running = false;
            });
        };
        obj.addEventListener(type, func);
    };

    /* init - you can init any event */
    throttle("resize", "optimizedResize");
})();

// Событие, сюда ваш код
window.addEventListener("optimizedResize", function() {
    testFunction(); // вызов той самой функции
});


// Функция, чтобы было удобно вызвать
function testFunction() {
    const el = document.getElementById('ButtonOnPreview');

    if (window.innerWidth < 769){
        el.classList.add('preview_main_button_2');
        el.classList.remove('preview_main_button');
    } else {
        el.classList.add('preview_main_button');
        el.classList.remove('preview_main_button_2');
    }

}
// Вызов функции, чтобы она срабатывала при загрузке
testFunction();
```

```css
    .preview_main_button{
        background: red;
    }
    .preview_main_button_2{
        background: green;
    }
```

```html
<div class="preview_main_button" id="ButtonOnPreview">Перейти ко всем статьям</div>
```